# Show sum of two polyhedral cones is a polyhedral cone?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-cone

Polyhedral cone is defined as $C= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax \geq 0\}$. Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be two polyhedral cones in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $C_1+C_2$ is also a polyhedral cone.

My try: Let $x + y \in C_1 + C_2$ we need to show there is a matrix $D$ such that $D(x+y) \geq 0$. To show that we need to use the facts that $x \in C_1 \rightarrow Ax \geq 0$ and $y \in C_2 \rightarrow By \geq 0$ for some appropriate $A$ and $B$.

My question: How can we use $A$ and $B$ to connect them to $D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $z\in C_1+C_2$ if and only if there are $x,y$ such that $x+y=z$, $Ax\ge0$, $Bx\ge0$. That is, $z$ is the third component of vectors
in the cone
$$
\left\{ (x,y,z) \in (\mathbb R^n)^3: 
\pmatrix{I & I & -I \\ -I&-I&I \\  A & 0&0\\0&B&0}
\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}\ge \pmatrix{ 0\\0\\0\\0}
\right\}.
$$
Now use [Fourier-Motzkin elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Motzkin_elimination) to compute the projection onto the $z$-component. It follows that $C_1+C_2$ is a polyhedral cone.